# Validate Input if Submitted (ie, "not disabled")

Tags: php, validation

I have a contact form that is being submitted, I have PHP validation all set up before it sends the email, however, I have 2 fields that are **dynamically** disabled or enabled based on the link clicked to get to the contact form.

I need to know how to determine whether they are disabled or not and then validate them only if they're not disabled.

Here's part of my form:

```
<label for="name">Name</label><br />
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

<label for="email">Email</label><br />
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />

<label for="number">Phone Number</label><br />
<input type="text" name="number" id="number" />

<div id="date-time">
    <label for="date">Date</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="date" id="date" <?php
        if (!isset($_GET["appt"])==true) echo('disabled="disabled"'); ?> />

    <label for="time">Time</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="time" id="time" <?php
        if (!isset($_GET["appt"])==true) echo('disabled="disabled"'); ?> />
</div>
```

Here's part of my `mail.php` file (disregard the `cookie` functions):

```
    $name   = trim($_POST["name"]);
    $email  = trim($_POST["email"]);
    $phone  = trim($_POST["phone"]);
    $date   = trim($_POST["date"]);
    $time   = trim($_POST["time"]);

//Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
    if($name == NULL) {
        $hasError = true;
        $emailSent = false;
        cookie("hasError", "true");
        cookie("nameError", "true");
    } else {
        $name = $name;
    }

//Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
    if($email == NULL) {
        $hasError = true;
        $emailSent = false;
        cookie("hasError", "true");
        cookie("emailError", "true");
    } else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", $email)) {
        $hasError = true;
        $emailSent = false;
        cookie("hasError", "true");
        cookie("emailError", "true");
    } else {
        $email = $email;
    }

//Check to make sure that the phone field is not empty
    if($phone == '' || $phone < 10) {
        $hasError = true;
        $emailSent = false;
        cookie("hasError", "true");
        cookie("phoneError", "true");
    } else {
        $phone = $phone;
    }

//Check to make sure that the date field is not empty
    if($date == '') {
        $hasError = true;
        $emailSent = false;
        cookie("hasError", "true");
        cookie("dateError", "true");
    } else {
        $date = $date;
    }

//Check to make sure that the time field is not empty
    if($time == '') {
        $hasError = true;
        $emailSent = false;
        cookie("hasError", "true");
        cookie("timeError", "true");
    } else {
        $time = $time;
    }
```

I'm still learning my way around PHP so thanks in advance for any help you can give. :)

**//EDIT**

`appt` is from a URL query string. Even if the query string is not present & the inputs are disabled, I'm using jQuery to add or remove `disabled` from the inputs upon clicking a link on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isset($_POST['date'])` to check if the value is set during the submit, cos, if the fields that are disabled will not be submitted in the form right.

**EDIT**

You might face a problem here, as it is very easy to tamper with the form in client side and pass both `date` and `time` here. So the best thing you can do here is have a hidden field which you set with either `date` or `time` along with setting the "dynamic" fields disabled. So, in the server side, just read the hidden field and read the required value accordingly.

Comment: So I could say `$date = isset(trim($_POST["date"]));` and then **if** `$date` is NULL, it will just skip over my validation code?

Comment: Re: your edit. I don't know about you, but I have a proxy server. I can completely re-write all of the post values before they are sent. We can't account for that while developing. We need to be able to expect that the user don't break the internet.

Comment: First could you pls tell me how you know which field to disable , cos you have used `(!isset($_GET["appt"]))` for both.

Comment: @Balanivash Well, technically, I can tamper with the hidden fields as well, so how do they help?

Comment: @cwallenpols : true, but this is just a small precaution we can take right.

Comment: @mc10: we can tamper with hidden fields also, but here we know that the hidden field has only 2 possible values, if it is anything other than these 2, we know that the form has been tampered with and act accordingly

Comment: `appt` is from a URL query string. Even if the query string is not present & the inputs are disabled, I'm using jQuery to add or remove `disabled` from the inputs upon clicking a link on the page. Edited my original post with this info, too.

Comment: @Max: what you can do is, have a variable lets say `$datetime` and you set this with the value of your hidden variable, and then just do, `if($datetime=="date"){$date = trim($_POST["date"])} else if($datetime=="time") ($time =trim($_POST["time"]) )`

Comment: @Balanivash What I mean is that you could switch from "false" to "true" (for instance) and fake `time` and `date` values.

Comment: Thanks Balanivash, I used **`if (isset($_POST["date"])) { //validation code }`**. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken, but shouldn't the indexes simply not exist if the inputs are disabled? Meaning `if !isset($_POST[<index>])` don't validate.

Oh, BTW `!isset($_GET["appt"])==TRUE` is redundant. Just use `!isset($_GET["appt"])`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that first part, could you elaborate? Thanks for that last bit, though.

Comment: if a field is disabled in the form , the index is not a part of the `$_POST` array. So you are checking if the index is set ion the array. Thats all :)

Answer (score 0):

On the form page, put $_GET["appt"] in a hidden field. Since it is what you used to determine whether or not the fields should be disabled, passing it along to the PHP validating page can let you determine whether or not you disabled the fields on the form page.

On the form page:
    " />

And on the mail.php page:

```
$disabled = trim($_POST["disabled_var"]);
```

If true, the elements were disabled.

Also, no, you can't just see whether or not they exist in the post, because they could very much be empty (but enabled).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden field for each field, and set them to values that you can extract. Probably not the most elegant solution, but it still works.

```
<input type="hidden" name="datedisabled" id="datedisabled" value="<?php
        if (!isset($_GET["appt"])) { echo 'true'; } else { echo 'false'; } ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="timedisabled" id="timedisabled" value="<?php
        if (!isset($_GET["appt"])) { echo 'true'; } else { echo 'false'; } ?>" />
```

Then, you can check with PHP.

By the way, doing explicit checks like `if ($a == true)` are redundant. Just do `if ($a)`.

Comment: I'd like to not add any hidden fields to the form if at all possible. Thanks for that last tip, though! Always learning :D